# Не получается получить значение с textarea при помощи val();

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
jQuery("#submit").on('click', function() {
    var email, name, subject, message;

    email = jQuery("#email").val().trim();
    name = jQuery("#name").val().trim();
    subject = jQuery("#subject").val().trim();
    message = jQuery("#message").val().trim();

    jQuery('#errormessage').text('');

    if (name == "") {
      jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите имя');
      return false;
    } else if (email == "") {
      jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите e-mail');
      return false;
    } else if (subject == "") {
      jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите тему сообщения');
      return false;
    } else(message == "") {
      jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите сообщение длиной не менее 5-ти символов');
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contwindows"><br><br><br><br>
  <span><strong> NAME:</strong></span> <br><br>
  <textarea name="areaname" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Name" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='nme'></textarea><br><br>

  <span><strong> EMAIL:</strong></span> <br><br>
  <textarea name="areamail" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Email" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='mail'></textarea> <br><br>

  <span><strong> SUBJECT:</strong></span> <br><br>
  <textarea name="areasubject" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Subject" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='sbject'></textarea> <br><br>

  <span><strong> YOUR MESSAGE:</strong></span> <br><br>
  <textarea name="areamessage" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Message" required="1" cols="33" rows="4" id='messge'></textarea> <br><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="bottom"><br>
  <div id="errormessage"></div>
</div>
```

Здравствуйте, уважаемое сообщество, прошу вашей помощи. Вот участок кода, ничего не работает. Не выдает абсолютно ничего.
Я попытался сделать ввод через `prompt()`, и всё супер. Как я понимаю, при использовании `val()` переменные не получают никакого значения, но понять почему я не могу. 
[image: вот как выглядит всё это дело]

В консоли пишет следующее:
[Intervention] Slow network is detected. See  for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: 
8A - cookie associated with a cross-site resource at  was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at  and .
embed_lib_v0.0.5.js:1 [TikTok] We're hiring!Are you ready to make a change?Check out some of our available positions at https://careers.tiktok.com/
perpetka.html:1 A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: А что? Все id специально не совпадают?

Answer (score 5):

```js
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function(){
            var email, name, subject, message;

            email = jQuery("#email").val();
            name = jQuery("#name").val();
            subject = jQuery("#subject").val();
            message = jQuery("#message").val();

            jQuery('#errormessage').text('');

            if (name == "") {
                $('#errormessage').text('Введите имя');
            } else {
                name = name.trim();
            }
            if (email == "") {
                jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите e-mail');
            } else {
                email = email.trim();
            }
            if (subject == "") {
                jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите тему сообщения');
            } else {
                subject = subject.trim();
            }
            if (message == "") {
                jQuery('#errormessage').text('Введите сообщение длиной не менее 5-ти символов');
            } else {
                message = message.trim();
            }
        })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><strong>  NAME:</strong></span> <br><br>
    <textarea name="areaname" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Name" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='name' ></textarea><br><br>

    <span><strong>  EMAIL:</strong></span> <br><br>
    <textarea name="areamail" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Email" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='email'></textarea> <br><br>

    <span><strong>  SUBJECT:</strong></span> <br><br>
    <textarea name="areasubject" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Subject" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='subject'></textarea> <br><br>

    <span><strong>  YOUR MESSAGE:</strong></span> <br><br>
    <textarea name="areamessage" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Message" required="1" cols="33" rows="4" id='message' ></textarea> <br><br>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="bottom"><br>
    <div id="errormessage"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ИСПРАВЬТЕ ВСЕ **ID**:

```
<div id="contwindows"><br><br><br><br>
        <span><strong>  NAME:</strong></span> <br><br>
        <textarea name="areaname" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Name" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='name' ></textarea><br><br>

        <span><strong>  EMAIL:</strong></span> <br><br>
        <textarea name="areamail" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Email" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='email'></textarea> <br><br>

        <span><strong>  SUBJECT:</strong></span> <br><br>
        <textarea name="areasubject" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Subject" required="1" cols="27" rows="1" id='subject'></textarea> <br><br>

        <span><strong>  YOUR MESSAGE:</strong></span> <br><br>
        <textarea name="areamessage" placeholder="Remember, be nice!" title="Message" required="1" cols="33" rows="4" id='message' ></textarea> <br><br>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="bottom"><br>
        <div id="errormessage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да и ошибка в выражении `else(условие){}`. Denis640Kb все написал))

Comment: да, это я мудрил с id, дело в том, что и с правильными id, и то, что после else не должно быть условия я замечал, но все-равно ничего не работает. Я не понимаю почему, я смотрел видео с созданием формы, повторил всё точь в точь, но не работает. программа, написанная Денисом работает, но при вводе всех полей все-равно пишет "Введите имя", но суть в том, что я просто хочу понять, что я делаю не так.

Comment: У Дениса все работает, вроде. Я на JSFiddle исправил только id и if добавил и все работает. https://jsfiddle.net/efimleonid/z89cdq2w/4/. Посмотрите у здесь, посмотрите в консоли что выводит. Если что не так, пишите, будем посмотреть.

Comment: Хм, там все работает. А я столько нервов на это потратил..Вставил текст из консоли по фотографией

Comment: вот ссылка на страничку, можете посмотреть как это дело работает: https://kamilwork.space/

Comment: Ошибка записи в Cookie в Хроме, я так понял. Браузер воспринимает как внедрение. Надо смотреть в другом месте.